# How to set the selected value for a dropdownlistfor in a foreach loop

Tags: html, jquery, razor

I'm trying to either use a property or event of the dropdownlistFor to set the selected value for items in a foreach loop. I'd like to just set the selectedValue property, but I'm ok if I have to call a function when the ddl is loaded. I can't seem to get the right property or event.
It says i need to add more details, but i don't know how to be more clear.

```
@using GSET.Helpers
@model GSET_DAL.GSETDB.Model.KitConfiguration
@{
ViewBag.Title = "KIT CONFIGURATION (LOCKED)";
ViewBag.SubTitle = "<a class='btn btn-sm float-right btn-warning' href='" + Url.Action("Index", "KitConfiguration") + "'><i class='fas fa-backspace fa-lg' title= 'Back To Quote' data-toggle= 'tooltip' data-custom-class='tooltip-warning' data-placement='left'></i> Back To Kit Configuration</a>";

decimal TotalCost = 0.0M;
}
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header bg-gset">
    <span class="card-title">
        <i class="fas fa-lock mr-2"></i> CONFIGURATION #@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ConfigurationNumber)
    </span>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row mt-1">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Assigned Components</legend>
                <div id="divAssignedComponents" style="overflow-y: auto">
                    @foreach (var kitComponentConfiguration in Model.KitComponentConfigurations.OrderBy(x => x.PartNumber))
                    {
                        var bgColor = kitComponentConfiguration.IsDisabled ? "bg-gray-dark" : "bg-dark";
                        <div class="card @bgColor rounded mb-2 drag-drop-item" data-is-assembly="@kitComponentConfiguration.IsAssembly" data-pk="@kitComponentConfiguration.PKID" data-part-number="@kitComponentConfiguration.PartNumber">
                            <div class="card-body p-3 border rounded">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => kitComponentConfiguration.ServiceTabDisplay,
                                                    ViewBag.ServiceComponentDisplayLocations as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new
                                                    {
                                                        @class = "form-control",
                                                        id = $"tab{kitComponentConfiguration.KitComponentConfigurationID}",
                                                        onchange = $"SaveServiceValues({kitComponentConfiguration.KitComponentConfigurationID});"
                                                        //selectedValue = kitComponentConfiguration.ServiceTabDisplay
                                                        //or
                                                        //onload =  $"SetTabSelectedValue({id, kitComponentConfiguration.ServiceTabDisplay});"
                                                    })
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => kitComponentConfiguration.ServiceDisplayType, 
                                                    ViewBag.ServiceComponentDisplayTypes as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new 
                                                    { 
                                                        @class = "form-control", 
                                                        id=$"type{kitComponentConfiguration.KitComponentConfigurationID}", 
                                                        onchange = $"SaveServiceValues({kitComponentConfiguration.KitComponentConfigurationID});"
                                                        //selectedValue = kitComponentConfiguration.ServiceDisplayType
                                                        //or
                                                        //onload =  $"SetTypeSelectedValue({id, kitComponentConfiguration.ServiceDisplayType});"
                                                    })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/dlightful.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function SaveServiceValues(kitComponentConfigurationID) {
    debugger;
    var tabDisplay = $("#tab" + kitComponentConfigurationID.toString()).val();
    var displayType = $("#type" + kitComponentConfigurationID.toString()).val();

    //alert("id=" + kitComponentConfigurationID + ", tab=" + tabDisplay + ", Type=" + displayType);

    var saveIt = "@Url.Action("SaveComponentServiceSettings", "KitConfiguration")"
        + "?kitComponentConfigurationID=" + kitComponentConfigurationID
        + "&tabDisplay=" + tabDisplay + "&displayType=" + displayType;
    var response = callAjaxSync(saveIt);
    if (response.message !== "") {
        alert(response.message);
    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {

});
</script>
```

Comment: ViewBag.ServiceComponentDisplayLocations values are { {"Box", "Box"}, {"Primary", "Primary"), {"Auxiliary", "Auxiliary"} } ..... assume the database value for kitComponentConfiguration.ServiceTabDisplay is "Primary"

Comment: i ended up imbedding the definition of the select list in the DropDownListFor. I was the only way i could figure out how to set the selected value for each.

Comment: This works for this instance because the lists are short and not based on database data in the list. Wouldn't work most of the time. My next option was to create small view that had the two dropdowns that i would have to load into a div for each card in the group. That was alot more work. Got around it this time.